# How to get the total number of bytes from all files from a directory in C

Tags: c, linux, file, directory

I have the name of a directory, then I used chdir() to change the directory.
Now, how can I get the total number of bytes?

Thanks

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<wait.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

void print_cwd(){
    char cwd[100];
    memset(cwd,0,sizeof(cwd));
    printf("current directory: %s \n",getcwd(cwd,sizeof(cwd)));
}

int main(){

int fd[2],nbytes;
pid_t childpid;
char string[]="hello world!\n";
char sir[80];
char readbuffer[80];
pipe(fd);

if ((childpid=fork())<0){
    printf("error");
    exit(1);
}
if (childpid==0){
    close(fd[0]);
    scanf("%s",sir);
    write(fd[1],sir,(strlen(sir)+1));
    exit(0);
}
else{
    close(fd[1]);
    nbytes=read(fd[0],readbuffer,sizeof(readbuffer));
    chdir(readbuffer);
    print_cwd();
}

return(0);

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a code example of your problem?

Comment: Get the list of the file using `readdir`, then use `stat` to get the size of the files.

Comment: I wrote it. @PrestonM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `opendir`(3) + `readdir`(3) + `closedir`(3) to obtain the contents of the directory.

Use `stat`(2) to obtain the type of file and the size of each directory entry.

Tip: Don't forget that `readdir` only returns the file name, not a path to the file. You will you will need to prepend the path passed to `opendir` to the file names received from `readdir` to obtain a path you can provide to `stat`.

---

Alternativly, `dup2`(2) to make fd 1 (stdout) a copy of the writer end of the pipe, then use `execlp`(3) to execute `du` with arguments `-bs` and the path. This will send something like the following to the parent:

```
12345 /the/provided/path
```

Comment: If I'm working with the current directory, it is still necessary to use opendir?

Comment: Yes. It creates the handle used by `readdir`. /// There's no reason to call `chdir`.

Answer (score 0):

Practically speaking, combining `opendir()`, `readdir()` and `lstat()` in a recursive function we have the following code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>


long long dirsize( const char * dir )
{
    DIR * dp = NULL;
    struct dirent * entry = NULL;
    struct stat statbuf;
    long long size = 0L;

    dp = opendir(dir);

    /* Cannot open directory: Ignoring... */
    if(!dp)
        return 0L;

    while( (entry = readdir(dp)) != NULL )
    {
        /* Get file status... */
        lstat( entry->d_name, &statbuf );

        /* Regular file found... */
        if( S_ISREG( statbuf.st_mode ) )
        {
            size += statbuf.st_size;
        }
        /* Directory found... */
        else if( S_ISDIR( statbuf.st_mode ) )
        {
            /* Ignore "." and ".." directories */
            if( !strcmp( ".", entry->d_name ) || !strcmp( "..", entry->d_name ) )
                continue;

            /* Recurse at a new directory */
            size += dirsize( entry->d_name );
        }
    }

    closedir(dp);

    return size;
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    if( argc < 1 )
        return 1;

    fprintf( stdout, "%lld Bytes\n", dirsize( argv[1] ) );

    return 0;
}

/* eof */
```

Compiling:

```
$ gcc -Wall dirsize.c -o dirsize
```

Testing:

```
$ ./dirsize /tmp
120743918 Bytes
```

Comment: @Scusf0, The posted program returns `0` when it's unable to open the directory (when `!dp`). In that situation, `errno` will be set with an error code you can check (or output using `perror`).

Comment: @Lacobus did the error I warned about in my answer. They forgot to prefix the file name with the directory path before using it as a path.